# Convert List to json object in Talend

Tags: talend

I'm trying to convert list result from tJava Component to json object.
Result from tjava component is below.

```
[{run_id=5d0753d58d93b71a1d12cc22_, parent_run_id=null, pipe_invoker=scheduled, path_id=shared, count=33, plex_path=null, invoker=abc.com, nested_pipeline=true, duration=355, start_time=2020-11-20T11:17:32.298000+00:00, lable=MP_SQS, state=Completed, key=57694b41ee, root_ruuid=2_ba32ea346}, {run_id=5bd4c6ea346, parent_run_id=null, pipe_invoker=scheduled, path_id=shared, count=33, plex_path=null, invoker=wwr.com, nested_pipeline=true, duration=355, start_time=2020-11-20T11:17:32.298000+00:00, lable=Summary_MP_SQS, state=Completed, key=55dfff4f, root_ruuid=1246d2-8bdc-1846}]
```

i tried using tConvertType, or in tMapper converting into String then replace all function multiple time and then storing result into json file but noting is working as expected.
End Expected result is json file from above result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way with a Talend component to do that (but I may be wrong :-) ) :

1. Put quotes on the keys/value
2. Replace "=" by ":"

But it can be done with regular Java code, here an example :

```java
    String input = 
       "[{run_id=1111, parent_run_id=null1, pipe_invoker=scheduled1, path_id=shared, count=33, plex_path=null}," +
       " {run_id=2222, parent_run_id=null2, pipe_invoker=scheduled2, path_id=shared, count=33, plex_path=null}]";
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    
    input = input.substring(2,input.length() - 2); // remove "[{" .... "}]"
    output.append("[{");
    
    String step1 [] = input.split("\\}, \\{");  // each record, split on "}, {"
    int j = 1;
    for (String record : step1) {
       String step2 [] = record.split(",");   // each key/value, split on ","
       int i = 1;
       for (String keyValue : step2) {
          // key=value --> "key":"value"
          output.append("\"" + keyValue.split("=")[0].trim() + "\":\"" + keyValue.split("=")[1].trim() + "\"");
          if (i++ < step2.length ) {
             output.append(",");
          }
       }
       if (j++ < step1.length ) {
          output.append("} , {");
       }
    }
    
    output.append("}]");
    
    /*
    output :
    [{"run_id":"1111","parent_run_id":"null1","pipe_invoker":"scheduled1","path_id":"shared","count":"33","plex_path":"null"} , {"run_id":"2222","parent_run_id":"null2","pipe_invoker":"scheduled2","path_id":"shared","count":"33","plex_path":"null"}]
    */
```